# how to set each collectionview cell size in one collectionview using storyboard and swfit?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

I have one collectionView in a viewController, and in this collectionView I have two collectionView Cells and each one has it's own cell identifier and size.

What I'm going to do , when user taps CardView button then collectionView will display cell items with Identifier "CardCell" size of 300x400.

And If user taps ListView, it will display cell items with identifier "ListCell" size of 300x100.

> Currently I'm detecting which cell to show, I created enum and
>   variable cellIndex.

```
enum CellIndexType: Int {
    case cardView
    case listView
}
var cellIndex = 0
```

> and If cellIndex equals to 0, vc will display "CardCell" and if 1,
>   will display "ListCell".

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = Cell()

    if cellIndex == CellIndexType.cardView.rawValue {
        if let reusableCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as? Cell {
            cell = reusableCell
        }
    } else {
        if let reusableCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ListCardCell", for: indexPath) as? Cell {
            cell = reusableCell
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

> Here is my viewController with two cells in one CollectionView.

[image]

> Here is how my viewController looks like.

[image]

> Here is how collectionView's attribute inspector and size inspector
>   look like.

[image]
[image]

But with my configurations in storyboard and code, it always displays cells size of 300x400.

In which way can I implement this logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, You must set collectionView's cell size to none at storyboard.

[image]

Secondly, use collectionView's `sizeForItemAt` func :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if self.cellIndex == 0{
        return CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
    } else if self.cellIndex == 1{
        return CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
    }
}
```

In addition, register your cells at `viewDidLoad`:

```
yourCollectionView.delegate = self
yourCollectionView.dataSource = self
yourCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CardCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CardCell")
yourCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ListCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ListCell")
yourCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: estimate size is already set to none, and sizeForItemAt method is not working. ListCell is still fixed height 400.

Comment: @alphonse, are you reload your collectionView data when detect the cellIndex changed?

Comment: yes of course.I even tried to set cellIndex to 1 at starting point. but same situation.

Comment: Did you register your cells?

Comment: no I created and configured cells only in storyboard. Should I register? How to do that?

Comment: I deleted existing cell from tableview in storyboard, created nib file set each cell size. in sizeForItemAt method , I just returned CGSize(width: 300, height: 100) without conditions to make sure if this method works.But still getting 400 height. So I put print("sizeForItemAt is called") inside sizeForItemAt method but it's not calling. Do you have any idea? Once more, estimate size in collectionview attribute is already set to none.

Comment: I figured out why sizeForItemAt was never called. I need to delegate UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol. now it works without creating and registering nib files.

Comment: I am glad for you, happy coding :)